# How to create new data type from JSON in AsyncTask and send it to another activity. Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm new in Android developing and it must be an a simple question, but i can't figure it out. 
My app get a json of the form:
`[
    {
        'src':1,
        'title':'The Black Eyed Peas - Lets Get It Started',
        'id':1,
        'slots':[0,10],
        'prev':[0,1,2,3]
    },
    {
        'src':2,
        'title':'Carly Ray Jepsen - Call Me Maybe',
        'id':2,
        'slots':[0,10],
        'prev':[0,1,2,3]
    },
    {
        'src':3,
        'title':'Kris Kross - Jump',
        'id':3,
        'slots':[0,10],
        'prev':[0,1,2,3]
    }, .... //several identical
]`
Then I parse it.

```
                 for(int i = 0; i<json.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) json.get(i);

                        String src = jo.getString("src");
                        String title = jo.getString("title");
                        String id = jo.getString("id");
                        //What should do next?

                      }
```

I need create an new data type to work with. How i must do  this?
PS Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement ParseAble class and send intent with object to another activity

```
    public class JSONDATA implements Parcelable {

        private String src;
        private String title;
        private String id;

        // Collect from json array
        public JSONDATA(JSONObject jo) {
            try {
                String src = jo.getString("src");
                String title = jo.getString("title");
                String id = jo.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static Parcelable.Creator<JSONDATA> getCreator() {
            return CREATOR;
        }

//read from Intent;
        private JSONDATA(Parcel in) {
            src = in.readString();
            title = in.readString();
            id = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(src);
            dest.writeString(title);
            dest.writeString(id);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<JSONDATA> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<JSONDATA>() {
            public JSONDATA createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new JSONDATA(in);
            }

            public JSONDATA[] newArray(int size) {
                return null;
            }
        };

    }
```

Then

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
    JSONDATA data = new JSONDATA(jo);
    intent.putExtra("DATA", data);
    sendBroadCastIntent(i,"YOUR_ACTIVITY");
```